# Applying a gradient to several UIViews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, gradient

I'm having some problems applying my gradient to more than one view, here's the code:

```
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = view6.bounds;
gradient.frame = view7.bounds;
gradient.frame = view8.bounds;
gradient.frame = view9.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:231.0/255.0 green:231.0/255.0 blue:231.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];
[view6.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
[view7.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
[view8.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
[view9.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

So what am I doing wrong? At the moment, the gradient is only being applied to view9 which has left me a bit stumped. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create layer every time when you want to add it to sublayer.

Good approach is create `GradientView:UIView` class than override `drawRect` method and draw gradient or add gradient layer to subview at another place in code. This way more useful, because if you want to change color of gradient you must change the code only in one place `(GradientView)`.

Another way is create method that will be build the gradient layer for each view.

```
- (CAGradientLayer *)gradientLayerWithFrame:(CGRect)frame colors:(NSArray *)colors
{
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = frame;
    gradient.colors = colors;
    return gradient;
}

...

NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:231.0/255.0 green:231.0/255.0 blue:231.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];

[view6.layer insertSublayer:[self gradientLayerWithFrame:view6.bounds colors:colors] atIndex:0];
[view7.layer insertSublayer:[self gradientLayerWithFrame:view7.bounds colors:colors] atIndex:0];
```

...

Answer (score 2):

You need to make 4 gradients, one per layer, but you can re-use the colors.

Currently, each time you add that layer as a sublayer, it is pulled out of the previous layer first.